# Serialization doesn't accept my KnownTypeAttribute, why?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I've got stuck with a serialization problem. My Silverlight app doesn't expect one of my properties in a businessobject and doesn't know what to do about it. Previously I have solved this by setting a KnownTypeAttribute like the example below but in this case it doesn't work.

I have used to solve it like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "baseClass")]
public class baseClass { }

[DataContract(Name = "busObj1")]
public class busObj1 : baseClass { }

[DataContract(Name = "busObj2")]
[KnownType(typeof(busObj1))]
public class busObj2 : baseClass
{
    public busObj1 myObj { get; set; }
}
```

The only difference know is that I have slightly different structure, like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "baseClass")]
public class baseClass { }

[DataContract(Name = "busObj1")]
public class busObj1 : baseClass { }

[DataContract(Name = "busObj2")]
[KnownType(typeof(busObj1))]
public class busObj2 : baseClass
{
    public busObj1 myObj { get; set; }
}

// This is the class that I want to send via WCF and that cannot be serialized
// because the serializer doesn't expect busObj1.
[DataContract(Name = "busObj3")]
public class busObj3 : busObj2 { }
```

I'm very thankful for any ideas of what could be wrong!

Regards, Clas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the known type attribute on your base object:

```
[DataContract(Name = "baseClass")]
[KnownType(typeof(busObj1))]
[KnownType(typeof(busObj2))]
[KnownType(typeof(busObj3))]
[KnownType(typeof(busObj4))]
public class baseClass { }

[DataContract(Name = "busObj1")]
public class busObj1 : baseClass { }

[DataContract(Name = "busObj2")]
public class busObj2 : baseClass { }

[DataContract(Name = "busObj3")]
public class busObj3 : busObj1
{
    public busObj2 myObj { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "busObj4")]
public class busObj4 : busObj3 { }
```

or if you don't want to pollute your domain models with those attribtues you could also [do it in your web.config or use the `ServiceKnownType` attribute on your Service Contract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845788/29407).

Comment: I haven't needed it before. Why in this case?

Comment: I don't know why you haven't needed it before. You haven't shown how your service contract looks like and what types are visible to the client.

Comment: Your solution did the trick for me although it still is a mystery to me why some solutions work sometimes and sometimes not. Thanks anyway!