# ServiceKnownType not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, datacontract

I have a service contract interface that looks like this:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(GeometricModelDescriptor))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(TemplateModelDescriptor))]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IModelRepository
{
    [OperationContract]
    ModelDescriptor GetDescriptor(ModelHandle model);
}
```

It uses some simple data-contract types like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class ModelDescriptor
{
    //...
}

[DataContract]
public sealed class GeometricModelDescriptor : ModelDescriptor
{
    //...
}
```

When I attempt to call the GetDescriptor method, I get a serialization exception indicating that the client proxy can't deserialize the type:

> Element 'http://tempuri.org/:GetDescriptorResult' contains data from a
>   type that maps to the name
>   'MyNamespace:GeometricModelDescriptor'. The
>   deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to
>   'GeometricModelDescriptor' to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list
>   of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

My understanding is that the ServiceKnownType attributes should prevent this exception.  What am I missing?

---

Folks have asked for the client code.  It's a bit involved, but here is the crux of the logic that generates the client proxy wrapper:

```
                var baseType = typeof(ClientBase<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TService));
                var proxyType = _module.DefineType("ProxyType" + typeof(TService).Name,
                                                     TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.Public,
                                                     baseType,
                                                     new[] { typeof(TService) });
                var constructor = proxyType.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public,
                                                              CallingConventions.HasThis,
                                                              new[] { typeof(ServiceEndpoint)});
                var il = constructor.GetILGenerator();
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, baseType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                              null,
                                                              new[] {typeof(ServiceEndpoint)},
                                                              null));
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                var interfaces = FlattenInterfaces(typeof(TService)).ToList();
                foreach (var interfaceType in interfaces)
                {
                    BuildInterfaceMethods(typeof(TService), proxyType, interfaceType);
                }
```

This creates a `ClientBase<IService>` descendent, which also implements `IService`.  The interface implementation (built via BuildInterfaceMethods) routes each method call through the protected Channel property provided by ClientBase.  The emitted class is the equivalent of this:

```
    public sealed class ModelRepositoryProxy : ClientBase<IModelRepository>, IModelRepository
    {
        //Constructor omitted for brevity...
        ModelDescriptor IModelRepository.GetDescriptor(ModelHandle model)
        {
            return Channel.GetDescriptor(model);
        }
    }
```

---

I ended up using a solution outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840435/wcf-client-having-problems-recognizing-serviceknowntypes), by calling the IDesign `AddGenericResolver` on the client for each service known type shortly after constructing it.  This registers a DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior that knows how to resolve the specified types.  It's not clear to me why this is necessary to allow the client to resolve the types, but it works.

Comment: When you created the client proxy are the `GeometricModelDescriptor` and `TemplateModelDescriptor` classes being generated?

Comment: @Darin, The model descriptor classes are coded by hand and stored in a compiled assembly that both the client and service sides reference.

Comment: What about the `IModelRepository` interface? Is it also defined in this shared class library?

Comment: Could you show your client side code, the way you are calling the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have problem on the client side, not on the server. The problem might be because of you have added `ServiceKnownType` attributes after you have generated the client.

Comment: I'm not generating my clients as C# code with a tool, but rather emitting them dynamically as IL at runtime.  Do I need to do something after I construct the `ClientBase<>` channel?  I was under the assumption that the channel would recognize the known types on the service interface.